# TFS2017 On-Prem - Build Web page is blank & images not showing

Tags: tfs, build, missing-features

There are a few cosmetic issues with a TFS server I've setup.

The Builds Page is blank and the images aren't showing:

[image]

The entire strip where the Build Definitions are displayed should look like this:

[image]

A less obvious problem is the images are not showing.

Does anyone know whats causing this? or how to troubleshoot it?

Note: All the other pages show up fine, Releases, Packages, Library & Task Groups, its only Builds that's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f787ef9a-5329-49f2-9f71-c126f15efb11/tfs-2017-missing-icons?forum=tfsgeneral) for the missing images:

> 1) Open IIS Manager (inetmgr)
>
> 2) Navigate to Sites > Team Foundation Server
>
> 3) Double click on the Authentication icon
>
> 4) Right Click on Anonymous Authentication and select "Edit..."
>
> 5) Anonymous user identity is normally set to IUSR. Change it to "Application pool identity".

So I did that:

[image]

And now the Build Definitions showing, but the images are still not showing. *Its so weird how running a fix for images (symptom) fixed the root cause, but the symptom is still not fixed*.

[image]

Edit:

After a IISRESET the images are now showing properly. Also note that a Build Agent I had setup and registered to a AgentPool was not showing either until I applied this fix.

ps:

The other thing I didn't try is setting the SPN for the service account:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61335/cannot-view-images-in-tfs-web-portal.html